# Heat capacity determination

Tags: heat

Since heat capacities are determined in a calorimeter taking advantage of the known heat capacity of water, how was the heat capacity of water originally determined?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297887/how-was-the-specific-heat-capacity-of-water-determined-experimentally

Comment: Actually used calorimetric tools like DSC calorimeters have nothing to do with heat capacity of water.

Comment: It looks to me like DSC calorimeters require a reference sample with known heat capacity.  Whether the reference is water or some other substance, the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The heat capacity of water was initially determined by doing mechanical work (moving a turbine) in the water until the temperature rose.

They then made the equivalency of mechanical and thermal energy from that.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  But I imagine that those early determinations weren't terribly precise.  So I'm guessing that heat capacities were gradually refined in some way that didn't depend solely on a well-defined reference heat capacity such as water or any other.  Perhaps the Dulong-Petit law was an early subsequent step.  Likely there were many refinements along the way.